# Change curser; div click scroll down to div

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make a div clickable in order to scroll down to another div. I also want to change the curser to be an up arrow while hovering over this clickable div, how might I achieve this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPoNrw

```
$("#top").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#middle").offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

Comment: In CSS you can use the cursor property to set it to [an image or other options](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/). And your code pen [didn't have jQuery](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daOyOa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codepen is fine, the only problem is that Jquery isn't called.
You can add sources and different CDNs via the settings.

See mine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVbobo

As for an up arrow on hover, I'm not quite sure there is an up arrow. Maybe you're looking for the 'pointer'.

In regards to how to do this on hover - see below

```
#top:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

You can change the cursor to anything stated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor)

I've made it a 'pointer' for the time being as I think it's the most suited for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You've done it correctly. The reason why it didn't work on your Codepen snippet is because you might have forgotten to add Jquery

[image: Codepen]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom image in your CSS to accomplish this.

See sample code below:

```css
.url {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='32px' height='32px' viewBox='0 0 512 512' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Cpath d='M249.628,176.101L138.421,52.88c-6.198-6.929-16.241-6.929-22.407,0l-0.381,0.636L4.648,176.101c-6.198,6.897-6.198,18.052,0,24.981l0.191,0.159c2.892,3.305,6.865,5.371,11.346,5.371h221.937c4.577,0,8.613-2.161,11.41-5.594l0.064,0.064C255.857,194.153,255.857,182.998,249.628,176.101z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='url'>clickable div</div>
```